# How to sort columns in SSAS?

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssas, ssas-tabular

I'm working on a tabular model in SSAS and I'd like columns to appear in a certain order for instance in Excel. The problem is that they are always sorted in alphabetical order.

[SSAS:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPBP5.png)

[How I see it in Excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFdFo.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For measures, you can drag them in Cube Structure -> Measures
[(picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QElka.png).

For dimensions, you can modify each hierarchy in Dimension Structure -> Hierarchies [(picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQAHw.png). Keep in mind this will impact your actual order in the hierarchy, not just the display.